# 404 Error Report - Maven project with JSF

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, web, http-status-code-404

I created a basic web maven project with JSF and some other dependencies.
Basically the project is a HelloWorld without any java class, only two pages: index.jsp and olamundo.xhtml. The problem is that when I access the link "localhost:8082/FinanceiroWeb/olamundo.**jsf**" **http 404 error occurs**, but when I access the link "localhost:8082/FinanceiroWeb/olamundo.**xhtml**" **works**. Do not know what I did wrong or left undone.

I use Apache Tomcat 7.0.

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>FinanceiroWeb</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Faces Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.financeiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>FinanceiroWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FinanceiroWeb Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <classifier>with-deps</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Server Faces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>FinanceiroWeb</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**olamundo.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Teste inicial JSF</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="Olá Mundo!" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```xml
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With your given configuration, if *olamundo.xhtml* exists, you would retrieve it properly processed when typing *olamundo.jsf* and in raw facelet code when typing *olamundo.xhtml*. The url-pattern part of the faces servlet specifies which requests will hit the faces servlet.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But when I try to access the page by url **olamundo.jsf** shows the 404 error, and when access to **olamundo.xhtml** url works. What setting is wrong?

Comment: You've got a lot of stuff which is uneccesary or unrelated to the problem. JSF 2 is intended to work with facelets format, xhtml. Forget about the other extensions, as they're unrelated. Stick to xhtml. Also configure your servlet mapping to use xhtml pattern too. I don't understand why you've got several welcome files, even they seem not to be tied to your problem...

Comment: In fact, when I created the project the various files welcome were already configured, I see no problem with that. I am studying a book on JSF and the author uses throughout the entire book the url-pattern *.jsf and to not have any problems during the book, I decided to go the same way as the author. Could you tell me or recommend me material on best practices for JSF?

Comment: Go with a pure JSF 2 tutorial. There are many things that changed since 1.x ages. One of them is the url-pattern, which was previously suggested to be `*.jsf` and now is `*.xhtml`, that way you always hide your facelet raw code (.xhtml) files to the end user. JSF 2 first spec was done in 2009, it is mature enough not to consider 1.x anymore for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

index.jsp

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"  
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt">  


    <head>  
      <title>Sample Application</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
     <c:redirect url="olamundo.xhtml"></c:redirect>  

    </body>  
  </html>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: The code you showed the **index.jsp** page is not redirected to the page **olamundo.xhtml**, this continues the **index.jsp** page. When I access the page **olamundo.xhtml** the url in the browser works the same as before the **web.xml** configuration, but the Faces Servlet is even getting requests with this configuration **web.xml**? If so, why not work with `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>`?